# .net clr method table structure

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I'm currently reading book titled Pro .NET Performance. One of its chapters contains detailed information about reference types internal structure. Method table is one of the internal fields of reference type layout structure. It is said in this book that method table consists of information about ALL methods of a class. I'm trying to check this theory with a little program

```
class MyClass
{
    public void M()
    {
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     MyClass m = new MyClass();
     m.M();
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I start this program with WinDbg
My WinDbg session looks like the following

```
!clrstack -a
ConsoleApp.Program.Main(System.String[]) [c:\visual studio 2012\Projects\Algorithms\ConsoleApp\Program.cs @ 36]
    PARAMETERS:
        args (0x00bff274) = 0x02ba2fbc
    LOCALS:
        0x00bff270 = 0x02ba2fd8
```

0x02ba2fd8 - is the address of MyClass instance
What I do next is try to dump MyClass instance

```
!do 0x02ba2fd8

Name:        ConsoleApp.MyClass
MethodTable: 00f84d74
EEClass:     00f81840
Size:        12(0xc) bytes
File:        C:\visual studio 2012\Projects\Algorithms\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp.exe
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
601a4544  4000001        4         System.Int32  1 instance       10 Z
```

Next step is to dump method table (its address is 00f84d74)

```
!dumpmt -md 00f84d74

EEClass:         00f81840
Module:          00f83fbc
Name:            ConsoleApp.MyClass
mdToken:         02000002
File:            C:\visual studio 2012\Projects\Algorithms\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp.exe
BaseSize:        0xc
ComponentSize:   0x0
Slots in VTable: 6
Number of IFaces in IFaceMap: 0
--------------------------------------
MethodDesc Table
   Entry MethodDe    JIT Name
6005a2c8 5fcf8354 PreJIT System.Object.ToString()
60065600 5fcf835c PreJIT System.Object.Equals(System.Object)
600319b0 5fcf837c PreJIT System.Object.GetHashCode()
600316e8 5fcf8390 PreJIT System.Object.Finalize()
012604c0 00f84d6c    JIT ConsoleApp.MyClass..ctor()
012604f8 00f84d60    JIT ConsoleApp.MyClass.M()
```

The output from !dumpmt command shows that method table contains entry for M() method. But when I try to dump memory at address 00f84d74

```
dd  00f84d74

00f84d74  00000200 0000000c 00024188 00000004
00f84d84  601a299c 00f83fbc 00f84db0 00f81840
00f84d94  012604c0 00000000 00f84da0 6005a2c8
00f84da4  60065600 600319b0 600316e8 00000080
00f84db4  00000000 03ba3500 00000000 03ba3504
00f84dc4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00f84dd4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00f84de4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

I can't find any references to address of M() method (012604f8)

So the question is whether method table contains references to non-virtual methods? Where are they stored?

Comment: 012604f8 is the address of the metadata description of the method.  The method table contains more than just the method addresses.  The 4 virtual methods inherited from Object start at 00f84da0 (6005a2c8 etc), the two methods of the class are not jitted yet.

Comment: Thank you, Hans. Method M() is already JIT-compiled. But there is no entry in method table for M().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

Thanks to one of my colleagues who shed some light to my question. It turns out that method pointers are located at negative offsets relative to method table pointer