# !dumpmt contradicts !dd when analyzing .NET method table

Tags: .net, clr, windbg, sos, sosex

I'm inspecting .NET object internals using WinDBG and SOS. I have a class with 3 methods. When I dump the method table using `!dumpmt -md [address]` command I get a description of 8 methods.

When I dump memory using `dd [address]` command I can't find 3 methods (see image - pink box). Also value 0x0003 (in a red circle) seams strange because it should represent the total number of methods (including virtual) but it represent only number of non-virtual methods. And what does the value in black box stand for?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be .NET 4. IMHO the red circle is wrong. It should be around 00000004 instead. Non-virtual methods are located in front of the method table (negative offsets)., try `dd <address>-80`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201811/net-clr-method-table-structure

Comment: Thtank you! Where can I find some docs or specs related to this topic?

Comment: These internal layouts are subject to change. You'll hardly find official information about it. Try looking for blog posts from Sasha Goldshtein (@goldshtn) or other people who work in the .NET team.